# FFmpeg TLS : Protocol not found

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, openssl

I am trying to stream a video securely, and this is what I have tried:

Console 1

```
$ ffmpeg -i out.webm -f format tls://127.0.0.1:8554?listen&cert=test.crt&key=test.key
[1] 46061
[2] 46062    
$ ffmpeg version N-81392-ga453bbb Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 20160609
  configuration: --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-shared --enable-pic --enable-libvpx --prefix=/home/ytan/Dev/build-x64
  libavutil      55. 29.100 / 55. 29.100
  libavcodec     57. 54.100 / 57. 54.100
  libavformat    57. 47.101 / 57. 47.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 52.100 /  6. 52.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100

(...waiting indefinitely)
```

Console 2

```
$ ffplay tls://127.0.0.1:8554
ffplay version N-81392-ga453bbb Copyright (c) 2003-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 20160609
  configuration: 
  libavutil      55. 29.100 / 55. 29.100
  libavcodec     57. 54.100 / 57. 54.100
  libavformat    57. 47.101 / 57. 47.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 52.100 /  6. 52.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
tls://127.0.0.1:8554: Protocol not foundq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
$
```

I have generated my key and certificate using OpenSSL:

```
$ openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domain.key -x509 -days 365 -out domain.crt
$ sudo cp test.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
$ sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Can someone drop me a hint or a pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that tls is not included in ffmpeg by default.

```
$ ffplay -protocols
```

I listed all the protocols available and "tls" wasn't there. I had to rebuild my ffmpeg with the flag `--enable-openssl`.

Credits to Reindl and Moritz (ffmpeg user mailing list)

Comment: Not a good idea to post email addresses on public sites

Comment: Right. How silly of me.

Comment: Yeh your edit it better, retains credit to the users. cheers